# mysql - ordering by non standard date format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, format

I'm try to order some data in a database which in it's current format is set as dd/mm/yyyy. Is there a way I can replace the '/'s when selecting the results in the query?

i.e. in php i could use str_replace() and do it that way. I dont want to change the data in the table as it is used elsewhere within the site.

Comment: if at all possible, fix your schema to use the right datatypes.  This will only cause you problems later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can replace the '/'s when selecting the results in
>   the query?

Yes, there is.  MySQL offers plenty of [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).  Here's a simple example of how it works:

```
SELECT REPLACE(dateField1,'/','')
FROM myTable;
```

You also should be able to alter the data type using [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html) to a SIGNED or UNSIGNED integer.

```
CAST(REPLACE(dateField1,'/','') as SIGNED)
```

Comment: this will be marked as the correct answer as it does hat i asked but this doesnt help me. is there anyway to change the datatype on the fly?

Comment: you can also `order by REPLACE(dateField1,'/','')`

Comment: I ended up doing CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pm.meta_value,-4),SUBSTRING(pm.meta_value,-6, 2),SUBSTRING(pm.meta_value,1, 2)) it's only a smaal page so not worried about performance.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping he'd figure that one out on his own.

Comment: @PhilJackson edit made, if you still need to alter the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your string version of the date to a correctly useable date format.  I'd also recommend fixing your table structure so that this date is actually stored as a date, not a string.